# Adding paging controls to a full page touch swiper/slider - Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, swipe, hammer.js

## CLICK FOR FIDDLE

Below is a fully functional ***full page touch slider*** I have created using [**hammer.js**](http://hammerjs.github.io/)

You can `drag`, `swipe` or `pan` to navigate between pages.

The slider works as expected but I am now trying to create fallback navigation by adding two buttons so paging left and right can occur on click also.

---

### QUESTION

How can the hammer swipe left or right be called on click? *(Javascript or jQuery).*

**CURRENT ATTEMPT**

```
$('#Left').on('click', function() {
  HammerCarousel(document.querySelector('.Swiper'), 'Left');
});
```

---

## FULL CODE

```js
function swipe() {
  var reqAnimationFrame = (function () {
    return window[Hammer.prefixed(window, "requestAnimationFrame")] || function (callback) {
      setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
  })();

  function dirProp(direction, hProp, vProp) {
    return (direction & Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL) ? hProp : vProp
  }

  function HammerCarousel(container, direction) {
    this.container = container;
    this.direction = direction;
    this.panes = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.container.children, 0);
    this.containerSize = this.container[dirProp(direction, 'offsetWidth', 'offsetHeight')];
    this.currentIndex = 0;
    this.hammer = new Hammer.Manager(this.container);
    this.hammer.add(new Hammer.Pan({ direction: this.direction, threshold: 10 }));
    this.hammer.on("panstart panmove panend pancancel", Hammer.bindFn(this.onPan, this));
    this.show(this.currentIndex);
  }

  HammerCarousel.prototype = {
    show: function (showIndex, percent, animate) {
      showIndex = Math.max(0, Math.min(showIndex, this.panes.length - 1));
      percent = percent || 0;

      var className = this.container.className;
      if (animate) {
        if (className.indexOf('animate') === -1) {
          this.container.className += ' animate';
        }
      } else {
        if (className.indexOf('animate') !== -1) {
          this.container.className = className.replace('animate', '').trim();
        }
      }

      var paneIndex, pos, translate;        
      for (paneIndex = 0; paneIndex < this.panes.length; paneIndex++) {
        pos = (this.containerSize / 100) * (((paneIndex - showIndex) * 100) + percent);
        translate = 'translate3d(' + pos + 'px, 0, 0)';
        this.panes[paneIndex].style.transform = translate;
        this.panes[paneIndex].style.mozTransform = translate;
        this.panes[paneIndex].style.webkitTransform = translate;
      }
      this.currentIndex = showIndex;
    },

    onPan: function (ev) {
      var delta = dirProp(this.direction, ev.deltaX, ev.deltaY),
          percent = (100 / this.containerSize) * delta,
          animate = false;
      if (ev.type == 'panend' || ev.type == 'pancancel') {
        if (Math.abs(percent) > 20 && ev.type == 'panend') {
          this.currentIndex += (percent < 0) ? 1 : -1;
        }
        percent = 0;
        animate = true;
      }
      this.show(this.currentIndex, percent, animate);
    }
  };
    
  var outer = new HammerCarousel(document.querySelector('.Swiper'), Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL);
};

$(swipe);
```

```css
html,
body,
.Page,
.Swiper{
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
}
.Swiper{
  background:#666;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.Swiper.animate > .Page{
  transition:all .3s;
  -webkit-transition:all .3s;
}
.Page{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  padding:0 10px;
  font:42px Arial;
  color:#fff;
   padding-top:10%;
  text-align:center;
}
.Page:nth-child(odd) {
    background:#b00;
}
.Page:nth-child(even) {
    background:#58c;
}
#Left,
#Right{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    font:16px/3em Arial;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#Left{
    left:0;
}
#Right{
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Swiper">
    <div class="Page">PAGE 1<br/>DRAG LEFT</div>
    <div class="Page">PAGE 2<br/>SWIPE ME</div>
    <div class="Page">PAGE 3<br/>HOLD TO PAN</div>
    <div class="Page">PAGE 4<br/>FLICK TO GO BACK</div>
</div>

<div id="Left">Left</div>
<div id="Right">Right</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have crafted a jQuery solution for this that should satisfy the fallback you are looking for.

Some things to consider, though. In your example as well, page re-size is not accounted for. I have not done so in this either to remain consistent and solve the immediate issue, but you will notice I am grabbing the `$('.Page').width();` as a variable in this solution. I would recommend re-assigning this value if you do account for re-sizing. Also, a mix of swiping/clicking will throw this off. I *assume* since you indicated this will be a fallback, the user will receive one of the two experiences. If not, we'll need a way to update `tracker` on swipe events as well.

You'll notice `var tracker = { 'R': 0 }`. While naming *may* not be the best, `'R'` will account for how many right "swipes" (navigation clicks) the user has performed in a plus/minus 1 manner

```
<div id="Left" direction="L">Left</div>
<div id="Right" direction="R">Right</div>
```

---

```
$(function() {
    var width = $('.Page').width();
    var pages = $('.Page').length;
    var tracker = { 'R': 0 }

    $('#Right, #Left').click(function() {

        $(this).attr('direction') === 'R' ? 
            ((tracker.R < (pages - 1) ? tracker.R += 1 : pages)) : 
            (tracker.R > 0) ? (tracker.R -= 1) : 0;

        $('.Swiper').animate({ 'scrollLeft': $('.Page').width() * tracker.R  }, 250)
    });
});
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/1zzhwotz/)

Comment: Yes this works and is a good idea however it doesn't entirely fill my needs. The buttons are a fallback but they will be visible at the same time and I cannot guarantee the user won't attempt to use a combination of both swipe and click. I genuinely thought there would be an easy way to simply invoke the animate left/right from an onclick call.

Comment: I'd either update Tracker as a global var on your swipe callbacks, or find a way to not present both experiences to the user. Capability detection? Keeping the tracker accounted for really shouldn't be that difficult now. Can you fire code on a successful swipe? @Obsidian

Comment: Thanks @sal niro I will work with it. Thanks for the input and Good job.

Comment: @Obsidian did you make any progress on this?- definitely curious. I see you have awarded bounty would you be willing to accept answer if you feel this was satisfactory?

Comment: My apologies of coarse. Thanks for your help on this.